# Split string and only return first 5 words

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am new to Python and am starting with the basics.
I am trying to split a string and consequently only show the first 5 words.
The current code I have written only shows the first 5 letters from all words in stead of the first words, my code is:

```
fruitstal = "kiwi appel peer mandarijn banaan meloen ananas mango grapefruit"
lijst=fruitstal.split()
    [print (i[:4] for i in lijst]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try splitting up until the fifth occurrence of space, then splice together that resulting list by space:

```py
fruitstal = "kiwi appel peer mandarijn banaan meloen ananas mango grapefruit"
output = ' '.join(fruitstal.split(' ', 5)[:5])
print(output)  # kiwi appel peer mandarijn banaan
```

Answer (score 0):

This loops through all of the fruits in the list, prints them, then stops when it has done more than 4:

```
    fruitstal = "kiwi appel peer mandarin banaan meloen ananas mango grapefruit"
    lijst=fruitstal.split()
    a = 0
    for i in lijst:
        if a > 4:
            break
        print(i)
        a += 1
```

Comment: Works exactly how it should. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple split creates a list of all fruits then, select 5 first items:

```
fruitstal = "kiwi appel peer mandarijn banaan meloen ananas mango grapefruit"
print(fruitstal.split()[:5])
```